# identify pop up and kill it or press OK

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Although the following background information is not so relevant to the question, I am including it in case you are curious:

I am running:

```
xlWorkBook.RefreshAll();
```

on an Excel workbook, and sometimes I get this message:

[image]

Using c# .NET 3.5 I would like to get rid of this pop up immediately after detecting it.

**How can I programmatically detect it and close it / press OK?**

Please note that I want to be able to identify this pop up even if it is in the background!

Comment: I'd check with a timer Form.CanFocus. If false send keys "esc"

Comment: @aliassce thanks so much for your comment can you give slightly more info please?

Comment: @aliassce what if it is in the background?

Comment: If your application is winform just place a timer. In Timer Tick event check Form.CanFocus. If this value is false use sendkeys to send ESC key. That will close the dialog. If it is in background use form.Activate and form.TopMost=true

Comment: @aliassce i dont want to use sendkeys, i want something more robust because the user will be interacting with the application and other applications at the same time, so sending ESC will not work if its not focused right?

Comment: Yes sendkeys will work only if its in foreground

Comment: All you can do is chase pop ups. Interopt is not a server automation tool.  I agree with the answer from msmucker0527 for this.

Comment: @Blam thank you. his answer is absolutely correct! but i would like to knwo if there's something like this i can use as well? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2772/C-Popup-Killer

Comment: What part of chase pop ups was not clear.  Excel is not built as server tool and Microsoft is clear on that.  For the X (XLSX) Microsoft does offer an automation tool.

Comment: I tried using Excel automation to extract text from thousands of files.  I could never get rid of all the pop ups.

Comment: i see. well there's definitely a low level solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to set display alerts to false and avoid these

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: could you tell me if this could ALSO work for me, just for my educational purposes http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2772/C-Popup-Killer

Comment: It looks like that particular project is designed for Internet Explorer popups, not for alerts in Excel

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to suppress alert/popups. However, that should ideally not be correct behaviour. When we call `RefreshAll()` and an error popup is displayed, the excel does not refresh the data. It would still show the old data.

For solving this, you can keep `Application.DisplayAlerts=True` and create two threads: one would open excel application & call RefreshAll() and other would wait for specified time (say 20 mins). If the 1st thread did not return back in 20 mins (likely due to popup), the 2nd thread would kill excel process. The 1st thread will get released and it will log exception that the file is not refreshed.